# Best way to only keep blank newlines in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm making a simple way to parse some markdown-like text.  Let's pretend my string looks like this (with the \n characters shown)

```
hello this\n
is part of the same paragraph\n
\n
this is a separate paragraph\n
\n
\n
\n
this is another one!\n
```

Right now, I'm adding a new `<p>` tag per-line, which ends up looking like this -

```
<p>hello this</p>
<p>is part of the same paragraph</p>
<p></p>
<p>this is a separate paragraph</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>this is another one!</p>
```

I reduced this a little bit by using the `.squeeze("\n")` method in ruby.  Then my HTML would look like this-

```
<p>hello this</p>
<p>is part of the same paragraph</p>
<p>this is a separate paragraph</p>
<p>this is another one!</p>
```

As you can see, this gets rid of the extra `p`elements - however the first two lines are still split into paragraphs.

How can I achieve an effect similar to markdown where two returns are required for a new paragraph to occur?  e.g.

```
this is 
part of the same paragraph

new para!
```

becomes

```
this is part of the same paragraph
\n
new para!
```

which becomes...

```
<p>this is part of the same paragraph</p>
<p>new para!</p>
```

Is there a regex solution I'm forgetting, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick idea:

```
str = <<-STR
hello this
is part of the same paragraph

this is a separate paragraph



this is another one!
STR

result = ''

result << '<p>'
result << str.gsub!(/\n{2,}/, "</p>\n<p>")
result << '</p>'

puts result


# Output
<p>hello this
is part of the same paragraph</p>
<p>this is a separate paragraph</p>
<p>this is another one!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the block version of gsub:

```
str = "hello this
is part of the same paragraph

this is a separate paragraph



this is another one!
"

str.gsub!(/\n+/) { |newlines| newlines[/\n{2,}/] ? "\n" : " " }
str.each_line { |line| puts "<p>#{line.strip}</p>" }

# output
<p>hello this is part of the same paragraph</p>
<p>this is a separate paragraph</p>
<p>this is another one!</p>
```